# Unir DataFrame pyspark

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

Muy buenas, estoy utilizando pyspark y quiero unir 2 pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame, mis Dataframe tienen de nombre:
maxDF y minDF.
Estos son mis DF:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguna idea de como puedo hacerlo?

Comment: No tengo ni idea del modulobque utiliza, pero investiga si no tiene un función merge

Comment: Debes tener en cuenta algo respecto a tus datos para poder escoger que método utilizar: 1. Si la estructura de los dos DataFrame es la misma el "union" sería la solución más práctica y podrías ver todos tus registros en una sola columna a través de un DataFrame resultante. 2. Si existe alguna columna clave, algo como un join podría funcionar bastante bien y se retornarían los datos requeridos. ¡Espero que te sirva!

Answer (score 2):

Podrías utilizar el método [`union`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.union.html):

```
df = df1.withColumnRenamed('Mínimo', 'num') \
        .union(df2.withColumnRenamed('Máximo', 'num'))
```

Comment: @Felipe Pellicer. Con el método de "Unión" tengo entendido que nos muestra todos los datos de las columnas seleccionadas, es lo que yo intento hacer que en el resultado muestre todos los registros, pero no los muestra todos

Answer (score 0):

Si los *DataFrame* tubieran una columna que fuese el ID de cada fila pudieras usar el método `join` de la siguente manera:

```
df=maxDF.join(minDF, maxDF.ID == minDF.ID).drop('ID')
```